# SSRS Check Filtered Group RowCount

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I would like to check the RowCount of a filtered group from without the scope of the group.

I particularly would like to know when the group is empty so that I can set the `Hidden` property on another row in the table that is not in the group.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Frank

**UPDATE - SOLUTION FOUND:**

I found the answer to this question through trial and error. I moved the filter to the Tablix, and then I simply used the expression that follows (Note that there is no data region declaration) on the next row in the table after the group, which was in this instance the Details group:

```
=IIF(CountRows() = 0, false, true)
```

Note that to access a "Row" hidden property in Visual Studio 2008, only after enabling "Advanced Mode" on the grouping section of the designer you must select the row under "Row Groups" on the bottom of the designer, they are listed in top-to-bottom sequence. The properties are in the "Properties" pane to the right.

Comment: If you found an answer you need to answer and accept the question yourself to complete the question nd answer circle. [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `=IIF(CountRows() = 0, false, true)` to set the true and false value.